# ASN1 Macro Value "is referenced, but is not defined."

Tags: macros, asn.1

we try to make a macro in ASN1 but the compiler throws the following error:

```
line 6 (BIGINTMACRO): A0256W: 'BigIntValue' is referenced, but is not defined.
```

this is our code:

```
BIGINTMACRO DEFINITIONS ::=
BEGIN
  BIGINT MACRO ::=
  BEGIN
    TYPE NOTATION ::= <type ::= INTEGER>
    VALUE NOTATION ::= value (VALUE BigIntValue)     
    BigIntValue ::= Int1 Int2
    Int1 ::= number
    Int2 ::= number
  END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are still using the ASN.1 MACRO notation which was removed from ASN.1 in 1994 (20 years ago) and replaced by Information Object Classes and Parameterization? You will be much better off using modern ASN.1 rather than banging your head against a wall with ASN.1 Macro notation.

I notice that you are using either the OSS Nokalva ASN.1 compiler or the online ASN.1 compiler at http://asn1-playground.oss.com.  You should ask the OSS support department to assist you with this by sending mail to support@oss.com.  Although the OSS ASN.1 compiler still supports the ASN.1 macro notation, the support department can help you convert the macro notation to modern ASN.1.

Macro notation was removed from ASN.1 20 years ago because of its ambiguity as well as its inability to fully capture the macro author's intention in a machine processable way.  The modern ASN.1 Information Object Classes and Parameterization solved the problems inherent in the old ASN.1 MACRO notation.

In this particular case, what comes after the "VALUE" keyword is expected to be an ASN.1 type, not an additional macro production.

Comment: Hello Paul,
yes, there IS a particular reason I am still trying to use the ASN.1 MACRO Notation. We have a teacher who insists to use macro´s, but don´t ask me why...

Comment: Please ask him why he is teaching something that was removed from ASN.1 20 years ago because of inherent problems with it.  He should be focusing on the current version of ASN.1 unless he is trying to give a history lesson in bad ideas.

Comment: Thats his statement: "Since 1994 Macros were replaced by more modern language-concepts, but in the networkmanagement-standards they are still being used and so have to be understood" ...
PS: I translated it from german so it may not be perfect

Comment: @PaulThorpe Source about MACROs being deprecated?

Comment: @NeDark The ITU-T withdrew X.208 (Where ASN.1 MACRO were defined) after X.680 was published in 1994 (The replacement for X.208).  You can go to the ITU-T bookstore and look for X.208 to see its current status as "withdrawn".